# run npm i command errors

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to run `npm i` from `user` account, not `root` account, and I am getting this error

```
[user@server folder_a]$ npm i
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠴ idealTree:folder_a: sill idealTree buildDeps

#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: reservation_.SetPermissions( unprotect_start, unprotect_size, MemoryChunk::GetCodeModificationPermission()).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7fff628925f0
 1: 0xbe6ad1  [npm i]
 2: 0x1e42f64 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [npm i]
 3: 0xfa6cbe  [npm i]
 4: 0xfbb4c0 v8::internal::PagedSpace::SetCodeModificationPermissions() [npm i]
 5: 0xf32d33 v8::internal::CodeSpaceMemoryModificationScope::CodeSpaceMemoryModificationScope(v8::internal::Heap*) [npm i]
 6: 0xf50936 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [npm i]
 7: 0xf52568  [npm i]
 8: 0xf52ed8 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm i]
 9: 0xf5438a v8::internal::Heap::FinalizeIncrementalMarkingIfComplete(v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason) [npm i]
10: 0xf57e73 v8::internal::IncrementalMarkingJob::Task::RunInternal() [npm i]
11: 0xe328eb non-virtual thunk to v8::internal::CancelableTask::Run() [npm i]
12: 0xbe6ba4  [npm i]
13: 0xbea00e node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [npm i]
14: 0x16639e6  [npm i]
15: 0x1675f24  [npm i]
16: 0x166434e uv_run [npm i]
17: 0xabda2d node::SpinEventLoop(node::Environment*) [npm i]
18: 0xbc12d4 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [npm i]
19: 0xb364f4 node::LoadSnapshotDataAndRun(node::SnapshotData const**, node::InitializationResult const*) [npm i]
20: 0xb3a0ef node::Start(int, char**) [npm i]
21: 0x7ff532281d85 __libc_start_main [/lib64/libc.so.6]
22: 0xaba0fe _start [npm i]
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[user@server folder_a]$
```

I want to resolve this problem by running the command from `user` account not from `root`, I appreciate any suggestion to fix this issue

I use CSF and ImunifyAV for security.

###### System details:

- OS: AlmaLinux v8.8.0 STANDARD kvm
- cPanel Version 110.0.7
- npm 9.5.0
- Node v18.14.2

Answer (score 0):

It is impact of Cpanel "[Shell bomb protection](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/security-center/shell-fork-bomb-protection/)".

If you are server admin you can [create custom limits](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500001648681-How-to-create-custom-Fork-Bomb-Protection-settings) as need or just disable it at Home/Security Center/Shell Fork Bomb Protection.

As non root user you can't change this limits.